# How to find out where my functions errors are (CAKEPHP)

Tags: cakephp

I'm having trouble working out where I went wrong in my function and I would like to know if there was anyway for me to find out where the function breaks either using net beans or whilst I'm executing the function.

If you would like to see the function then here's a copy of it:

```
             public function archive($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $event =  $this->Event->read(null, $id);
        $archive['Archive'] = $event['Event'];
        $archive['Archive']['archiveID'] = $event['Event']['eventID'];
        unset($archive['Archive']['archiveID']);
        $this->loadModel('Archive');
        $this->Archive->create();
        if ($this->Archive->save($archive)) {
           // $this->Archive->invalidFields();
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'eventmanage'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been archived'));
          //  $this->Event->delete($id);  
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'eventmanage'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be archived, Please, contact the administrator.'));
        }
    }
}

so far i have tried using the `$errors = $this->Archive->validationErrors;` function but all i receive back is the word 'array'
```

**UPDATE**

I have got the event to save as an archive, however it does not send the message `$this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been archived'));` And it does not redirect back to eventmanage, it creates a new link to the /Controller/Action/id e.g. /events/archive/14 .

Thanks

Comment: Dont use echo, do pr($errors);

Comment: pr($errors); returns Array
(
) it now shows the () does that mean that my error was not in the archive database.. ?

Comment: what debug level are you using? `Config::write('debug', 2);` in your `app/Config/core.php`.

Comment: i have the Configure::write('debug', 2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `validationErrors` property returns an array. You can't echo an array object in PHP, as it's a collection of data, rather than something that can "just" be output to your screen. There are other functions to display the full array though, like [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump), [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) or the CakePHP methods [debug()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#basic-debugging) or [Debugger::dump()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#Debugger%3a%3adump). So try something like this:

```
$errors = $this->Archive->validationErrors;
if (!empty($errors)) { debug($errors); }
```

You can also use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) to output all the validation errors as a string in your flash message, for example:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be archived, because of the following errors: ' . implode('<br/>', $errors) . '. Please, contact the administrator.'));
```

That will display all the errors, separated with a break within the flash message.

**Update**
In regard to your latest question update, the flash message is not set, because you redirect before you set it. So, the statement is never reached. Swap the setFlash and redirect methods in your controller, so you'll get:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been archived'));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'eventmanage'));
```

Comment: the implode didn't return any errors, all i received was "The event could not be archived, because of the following errors: . Please, contact the administrator."

Comment: i updated my else statement so that you could see my else function updated

Comment: Try `$errors = $this->Archive->invalidFields();` instead, that might just do the trick.

Comment: that one is also an empty array, can i assume that my model is therefore valid?

Comment: It appears so. Do you have any `beforeSave` logic that might return false?

Comment: Can you also post a dump of `debug($this->request->data)` just before calling the `save()`?

Comment: how do i print out the result from the debug($this->request->data) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23516/discussion-between-oldskool-and-user1876222)

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding the need to assign a value to

```
$archive['Archive']['archiveID'] = $event['Event']['eventID'];
```

and unsetting it right after

```
unset($archive['Archive']['archiveID']);
```

If in your Db 'archiveID' is a required value, then I dont think MySQL would accept any data  if that value is not there.

You would have to check the structure your table.